# Angular 2 Aot : The selector "app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have generated aot by following steps in angular cookbook,

now I have aot folder with app, dist,node_modules,index-aot.html,shim.min.js and zone.min.js

When I run index-aot.hmtl I see below error

**The selector "my-app" did not match any elements**

Comment: Do you have a component declared in your AppModule with a selector my-app?

Comment: yes in appcomponent selector is my-app , actually I didnt find main.ts in newly generated aot folder , does it matter?

Comment: It should be present under app/main.ts indeed

Comment: you in aot/app/main.ts or in  normal  app folder,?